# New row in top of Excel table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a snippet of VBA code I'd like to enhance. Got two Excel tables - **ToDo** and **Done**. The code fetches first row in **ToDo** table (I use table header as anchor cell and offset one row down to get the value).

After some other features run, I want to add this value to **Done** table after which I delete it from the original **ToDo** table.

This all works - with the caveat that **ListRows.Add** function adds the new row to the bottom of the table as usual. Is there a way to add the new empty row & contents to the **top** of the **Done** table so that lastly processed values would run top-down, instead of bottom-up?

Some range reverse-order function probably messes up the overall sequence. Also adding a timestamp in .Range(2) and always do a sort feels too messy for workaround (there should be a neater way, right?)

```
Sub Data()

    Range("Data_transfer").Value = Range("ToDo_header").Offset(1).Value

    'some irrelevant code runs here

    Set newrow = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Done").ListRows.Add

    With newrow
    .Range(1) = Range("Data_transfer").Value
    End With

    Range("ToDo_header").Offset(1).Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you insert a row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add the new empty row to the top simply just add position

`Set newrow = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Done").ListRows.Add(1)`

Documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listrows.add) .